# get json content google maps angular2

Tags: json, angular, typescript, google-maps-api-3

[this](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=52.48278022207823,6.15234375) is a link to maps.googleapis.com. You get JSON information about the latitude and longitude in the url.

I need to read this JSON using Typescript and Angular2.

I tried a lot of different google suggestions and (among others) the following code (suggested by angular on [this link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#extract-data)):

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || {};
}
// this is fired when I click on my map, this.lat & this.lng are correctly filled
getLongLatClick($event: any) {
    this.lat = $event.coords.lat;
    this.lng = $event.coords.lng;
    this.url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+this.lat+','+this.lng+'';

    console.log(this.http.get(this.url).map(this.extractData));
```

But when I debug in chrome, the "extractData" methode doesn't run.. It seems that the googleapis link isn't JSON for some reason

What do I have to do to read the JSON?

Comment: console.log(this.http.get(this.url).map(this.extractData)).subscribe(data => data)

Comment: @otololua "Property subscribe does not exist on type 'void'"

Comment: @willemjan92 Have you checked your network tab, what you are receiving, if anything?

Comment: @willemjan92 ... and just realized that oto's code has one parenthesis on wrong place, therefore you are getting the void error. It should be: `console.log(this.http.get(this.url).map(this.extractData).s‌​ubscribe(data => data))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a **service** that makes the **http.get** to get the data, similiar to :

```
import { Injectable }   from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Response, Http, RequestOptions}  from "@angular/http";

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class DataService{

  private gmapsUrl: string = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=52.48278022207823,6.15234375';

  constructor(private http: Http) {};

  getAll() {
    return this.http.get(this.gmapsUrl).map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }

}
```

Cool, now you have a **service** that gets the data, which is also **injectable**. You can inject this service into any consumers you wish and **consume** the data. That is similar to :

```
import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef}  from '@angular/core';
import {DataService}        from "path";

@Component ({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'custom',
  templateUrl: //your metadata,
  styleUrls: //your metadata
})

export class ConsumerComponent implements OnInit{

  gmapsData: any = [];      

  constructor(private dataService:Data) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  private loadAllUsers() {
    this.dataService.getAll().subscribe(response=> {
      console.log(response.results); // 
      this.gmapsData = response;
    });

  }

}
```

Hope this helps -> This should give you a solid starting point.

What I haven't actually checked is the mapping between the response of the dataService.getAll() *inside* the consumer to the actual component property gmapsData, but you should be able to infer how to store it from the console.log(response);

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong code in your `extractData`. As you can see in the JSON response:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "20",
               "short_name" : "20",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            }
    .......
```

it has `results`, not `data`.

So it should be:

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.results || {};
}
```

So the following should work fine (using the static url in this example):

```
this.http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=52.48278022207823,6.15234375')
  .map(this.extractData)
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

Remember to always `subscribe` to get your response. And do consider making a service where you do the http-calls and `map` and then in your component call that service method and subscribe the results!

And it's good to check the network tab and see what the response looks like, and to see if you are getting a response at all.

Hope this helps! :)